# Open LiteSpeed permission problems

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions, litespeed

I recently moved to `open litespeed` from `apache` and i can no longer create files. 
When i do a `file_put_contents` i get permission errors.
`lsphp` and `litespeed` both run under user `nobody`.
Doing a chmod and changing permissions from 750 to 770 solves the problem but why do i need to do that.
Plus there are many files and directories and changing permissions on all of them is going to be tough.

Comment: Apache and OpenLitespeed use different methods for executing PHP scripts, which means that the processes have different owners. Therefore you need to change owners of the files so that they work with OpenLitespeed. You should check OpenLitespeed configuration help to see how it works.

Comment: Apparently it was due to the fact that i did not compile litespeed with correct user.
All my files were owned by my cpanel user and litespeed was compiled with nobody so it caused permission problems.  
Had to recompile litespeed from command line again and used `./configure --with-user=<fileowner> --wtih-group=<fileowner>`